# Windows services dependencies startup on different hosts

Tags: windows, service

I'd like to know if Windows allows me to configure Windows services dependencies among different hosts in the same network; in my case, these different hosts are different virtual machines belonging to the same application farm. Example: consider host1 with the database software and host2 with the application which uses the database. I want to configure the *host2.application* Windows service to run after the *host1.database* Windows service.

Thanks in advance
Simone

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am in need of the same thing